# Where is the root of cors blocking requests?

Tags: c++, ajax, cors

I've created an API with C++ and the following library: https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib

In the API I've added a header to responses for CORS:

```
svr.Post("/suggest", [&dr](const Request &req, Response &res){
    res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","(origin here)");
```

(origin here) is the origin of the server making the request.

On the browser side I've also enabled an extension to bypass CORS. But when trying to make an AJAX request to the API, I still get this error in my browser console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://192.168.1.10:10120/suggest. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

The AJAX request is done through a script written in the Tampermonkey extension to work on a specific website.

Do I need to modify headers on the server hosting the website? Have I done something wrong on the C++ side?

Also it might be important to mention that the code worked before. All I did was come back to it another day with a different local IP address (which i reprogrammed into the c++ API)

Comment: What are the HTTP status codes of the responses? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I tried looking at the error code and it worked again. This time it gave me an error about the self signed certificate, so i opened it in a new tab and added an exception. It started working again. It wasn't giving me this error before, not sure what's causing this inconsistency. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it again to answer @sideshowbarker and it gave me a new error about self signed certificates. After adding the exception it worked.